# Primefaces DataTable: selection not preserved after undo filtering

Tags: primefaces, filtering, selection

Im using:

- Primefaces v. 5.0
- JSF v. 2.1.3-FCS

I have noticed strange behavior in `dataTable` when filtering the table with selected row.

First, I fulfil  filter field with two characters so that result rows do not contain selected row. When I delete only one character from filter field so that result rows contain previously selected row, the selection is no enabled. When I delete second character, the selection is enabled again:

**Selected row before filtering:**
[image: selected row before filtering]

**Filtering with two characters, so that result rows do not contain selected row:**
[image: Filtering with two characters]

**Deleting one character from filter so that result rows contain previously selected row:** 
[image: Deleting one character]

**Deleting another character- previously selected row has selection enabled again:**
[image: Deleting another character]

My **xhtml**:

```
<h:form>
            <p:dataTable value="#{testTableBean.list}" 
                filteredValue="#{testTableBean.filteredList}" 
                selectionMode="single"
                selection="#{testTableBean.currentItem}" var="item"
                rowKey="#{item.id}">

                <p:column headerText="ID">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="name" filterBy="#{item.name}"
                    sortBy="#{item.name}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="value">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And my **bean**:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestTableBean {

  private List<TestTableItem> list;
  private List<TestTableItem> filteredList;
  private TestTableItem currentItem;

  {
    list = new ArrayList<TestTableItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      list.add(new TestTableItem(i, "hello" + i, 10 + i));
    }
  }

  public List<TestTableItem> getFilteredList() {
    return filteredList;
  }

  public void setFilteredList(List<TestTableItem> filteredList) {
    this.filteredList = filteredList;
  }


  public List<TestTableItem> getList() {
    return list;
  }

  public void setList(List<TestTableItem> list) {
    this.list = list;
  }

  public TestTableItem getCurrentItem() {
    return currentItem;
  }

  public void setCurrentItem(TestTableItem currentItem) {
    this.currentItem = currentItem;
  }
}
```

What I have found out, is that in `dataTable` the `selection` attribute is set based on list from `value` attribute and `value` attribute is set based on `filteredValue` attribute- if it is not `null`. The object from `selection` attribute is set before the list from `filteredValue` attribute is set, so that could cause situation in which `selection` is set based on previous filter action, but Im not sure.

The question is, is this behavior normal or is it a bug? And if it is a bug, are there any workarounds?

Comment: Tried PF 5.2 or even 5.3-Snapshot? Just to check if it is already solved

Comment: Yep, it is solved in PF 5.2. Still, it would be great to have some workaround for older versions....

Comment: Then do a diff of the related classes or javascript and create a small patch

Comment: It has turned out that PF 5.2 solves this issue by not clearing reference to selected object even when filtered rows do not contain previously selected row. It is quite problematic, as from the controller point of view the selection is still enabled (e.i. button that fires some action on selected row is still active). It is also hard to distinguish row selection programmatically as filteredValue attribute is set in render phase of jsf lifecycle...